# A nonlinear 4th order ODE, not sure how to solve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

Here is a problem I am not sure how the solution is arrived. It would be great if you could show how to obtain the given solution as in the question. Given the ODE, and the boundaries conditions, obtain P(r) in terms of W(r).

[image]

For those who are interested, the full questions is as such, 
[image]

Comment: What textbook are you using?  I don't know how to answer your question (yet), but I'm interested in learning, as I should really brush up on my DiffEq.  But the first thing I need to do is figure out what all that notation means, especially the overlines.

Comment: Please type out the images in your question, using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the Maths. Images are not always visible to users, and are not searchable on the site so less people will see your question

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, you can verify that the expression given for $P(r)$ satisfies the ODE.

To solve without the benefit of seeing the solution first define $F(r) = rP(r)$ and $G(r) = r W(r)$.  The ODE becomes $F^{(4)}(r) = G(r)$ and upon integration from $r$ to $R>r$ we get after rearranging,

$$\tag{1}F'''(r) = F'''(R)-\int_r^RG(y) \, dy$$

Integrating (1) and rearranging again we have

$$\tag{2}F''(r) = F''(R) - F'''(R)(R-r) + \int_r^R\left(\int_x^RG(y) \, dy \right)\, dx$$

In the double integral, the integration variable $x$ lies in the interval $[r,R]$ and we can introduce the indicator function

$$\mathbf{1}_{y \geqslant x} =\begin{cases} 1, & y \geqslant x \\0, & y < x\end{cases}$$
and manipulate the integral as

$$\begin {align} \int_r^R\left(\int_x^RG(y) \, dy \right)\, dx &= \int_r^R\left(\int_r^R\mathbf{1}_{y \geqslant x} G(y) \, dy \right)\, dx \\&= \int_r^R\left(\int_r^R\mathbf{1}_{y \geqslant x} G(y) \, dx \right)\, dy \\ &=  \int_r^R\left(\int_r^y G(y) \, dx \right)\, dy \\ &= \int_r^R (y-r)G(y) \, dy\end{align}$$

Using this result in (2) we get,

$$\tag{3}F''(r) = F''(R) - F'''(R)(R-r) + \int_r^R(y-r)G(y) \, dy $$

These steps can be repeated two more times to obtain

$$\tag{4}F(r) = F(R) - F'(R)(R-r) + \frac{1}{2}F''(r) (R-r)^2 - \frac{1}{6} F'''(R)(R-r)^3 \\+ \frac{1}{6}\int_r^R(y-r)^3G(y) \, dy $$

Assuming sufficient regularity, i.e., $\lim_{R \to \infty} R^kF^{(k)}(R) = 0$, we can take the limit of both sides of (4) as $R \to \infty$ to obtain

$$rP(r) = F(r) =\frac{1}{6}\int_r^\infty(y-r)^3G(y) \, dy =\frac{1}{6}\int_r^\infty(y-r)^3yW(y) \, dy,$$

and, thus,

$$P(r)  =\frac{1}{6r}\int_r^\infty y(y-r)^3W(y) \, dy$$